# How to check the view is dispose or not?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I need to access the Control is disposed property of xamarin.forms.Android. View from code but I can't able to access it while in debugging I can able to access it.`[one][1]`
[two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCA35.png)

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that `Control` and `Container` are not of the type `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ImageButtonRenderer` but of some kind of base class (if my assumption is correct this will be the `View` base class. `View` has no property `IsDisposed` so you can't access it on an object of that type. During debugging it's smart enough to notice that this current instance is of the type `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ImageButtonRenderer` which does have a property `IsDisposed`. So you could try something like this:

```
var control = Control ?? Container;
if (control is Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ImageButtonRenderer imageButtonRenderer)
{
    var isDisposed = imageButtonRenderer.IsDisposed;
}
```

Comment: IsDisposed.I have tried your above code IsDisposed property is not found.PLease guide thanks

Comment: Can you provide some more information on where we are in your code and what you're trying to do?